# Simple Script to copy missing cells from a new row on automated Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dom-events

My Google Spreadsheet is a simple table with 6 columns.
For each row:
- basic data is input on columns A, B, C by a zap that gets text and number data from external sources.
- columns D, E, F are formulas and hashes, generated by functions within the cells.

Every minute or so, my Zap brings a new row to my table, populating columns A, B, C automatically. Which also has the effect to erase other cells of that new row.

Therefore I need to run a script using function onEdit(e) in order for the missing cells of the newly created row, to be copied from the row above.

I made a few unsuccessful tries... Would love a bit of help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: onEdit() only fires for user edits. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) Perhaps you could put the formulas on another sheet and reference the data in columns A,B,C from the other sheet.

Comment: Hello! By Zap do you mean Zapier? Also, how many rows are inserted at once? How does the data look like? Could you provide a sample? Would it be feasible for you if there was a second Sheet to store the long-term data? Are you comfortable creating a web-app to handle this instead? Would you please add this information to your question? It will help others help you. Let me know and I'll provide you an answer that explains how to do it. Cheers!

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for the suggestion, it worked. I managed to get the data updated on one sheet, and the second to compute the new row by referencing the cell to my "data in" sheet. So the trick worked. But now I have another problem with running the scripts to compute one of my automated cell when the Spreadsheet is closed... It just cannot update in the background when closed.

Comment: I’m not trying to put you off. But it would give you greater access to all volunteers if you would pose your question as a separate question. Also please read [mcve].

Comment: @Julien I think you have it back-to-front. The sheet that is updated by Zapier is going to constantly change - so do NOT write any data to that sheet. Instead, an option is to create a second sheet into which the zapier sheet data is appended; any data that you write into this sheet is not going to be deleted, and, if necessary, you can sync the two sheets on, say, a timestamp field. onEdit, as mentioned elsewhere, is not suitable, rather look at a time-driven installable trigger. This might check the rows on the Zapier sheet that aren't on the "manual" sheet, and copy those 'new' rows over.